# How to rsync and grep only path of modified files in source directory

Tags: shell-script, rsync

Is there a way to just `grep` only changes ie; (add, delete, modified) and print path and file name using rsync.

I tried with below command but I am getting the path and file modified in separate line.

```
rsync -avnc $source $destination
source/10101/10102/10103/
source/10101/10102/10103/demo.fts
```

Note: There are more then thousands of sub directories in source, I want to print only files which are modified with absolute path.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/618735

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the directory path since that directory differs in its timestamp or user/group settings or permissions compared to the directory at the target.

To stop `rsync` from looking at the directory timestamps, use the `--omit-dir-times` flag:

```
rsync -avc -n --omit-dir-times "$source/" "$target"
```

Note that `rsync` will not show the absolute paths of the files and directories, but the path relative to the top directory being transferred.

Using `--itemize-changes` (or `-i`) in place of `--verbose` (or `-v`), you get a lot more information about *why* a file is being updated on the target.

Example (with added annotations in the output):

```
$ rsync -ani s/ t
.d..t...... ./          # directory timestamp differs
>f+++++++++ file        # new file

$ rsync -a s/ t

$ touch s/file
$ rsync -ani s/ t
>f..t...... file        # file timestamp differs

$ echo hello >s/file
$ rsync -ani s/ t
>f.st...... file        # file size and timestamp differs

$ rsync -acni s/ t
>fcst...... file        # file size timestamp and checksum differs

$ rm s/file
$ rsync -acni s/ t
.d..t...... ./          # directory timestamp differs
$ rsync -acni --delete s/ t
*deleting   file        # file has been deleted in source
.d..t...... ./          # directory timestamp differs
```

See the documentation for the `--itemize-changes` option in the `rsync` manual on your system.